# github project using tailwind css is showing 95%+ CSS and rest JS, HTML?

Tags: github, tailwind-css

Please note this is not duplicate of other similar questions asked, as they don't involved usage of tailwind css which is unique case.

I did create `.gitattributes` file and added below entry

```
*.js linguist-language=JavaScript
```

but it didn't fix the issue, still CSS usage is same.

Is tailwind css creating some hidden files which is shooting up CSS usage ?

Comment: Coming from your comment under my answer, I am wondering what kind of files are regarded as CSS? Are they `.css` files? Is it "regarding ALL `.css` files as JavaScript files" you need? If so, you need to change it as `*.css linguist-language=JavaScript`.

Comment: I'm using "tailwind css" framework for styling first time and it's causing CSS to shoot up. But with normal css styling project does show % of CSS usage properly. I'm confused what's going wrong when "tailwind css" comes into the picture ?

Comment: Are there any repository addresses for us to check what is going on?

Comment: https://github.com/vikramvi/instagram-clone

Comment: While opening this repository, I just see that it tells us "JavaScript 99.6%". But I noticed that there is a `src/styles/app.css` with a size of 3.4MB which seems pulling up the ratio of CSS before you used `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks for quick review, let me read about that file and add to .gitignore and check, can you please add your explanation in answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I updated my answer for your comment.

Comment: Please share more details - what is "the issue" you want to fix? What else have you tried to fix it?

Comment: @NicoHaase my project ( shared in comment earlier ) is same as https://github.com/karlhadwen/instagram but showing CSS usage 95%+, that's the issue I was trying to fix

Comment: https://github.com/karlhadwen/instagram/blob/master/src/styles/app.css this is original one which is much smaller in size than mine, need to figure out how is this generated by tailwind and is it stripped down later

Comment: Pleae add all clarification to your question by editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it didn't fix the issue

Yes. What you need to do is, asking GitHub Linguist for NOT seeing your CSS files (that is what you did now), or regarding your CSS files as some other types for example JavaScript.

> Is tailwind css creating some hidden files which is shooting up CSS usage ?

Yes. While opening your repository, I found a 3.4MB "large" file [`src/styles/app.css`](https://github.com/vikramvi/instagram-clone/blob/master/src/styles/app.css) which is probably the trouble maker.

---

Your comment said, "add to .gitignore and check". Please think twice:

1. Is your code run without this file? (or another question, is this file generated during code deploying which means your code can still deploys without this file?)
2. It is not enough for you to just add that file in `.gitignore`: Without other operation such as removing it from your Git repository (either via deleting it then `git add`, or use `git filter-branch` or `bfg` to remove the file from entire Git repository), it will be "useless" since that this file has already tracked by Git.

Comment: I re-checked original repo https://github.com/karlhadwen/instagram and it does as well have app.css file but is showing correct JS usage, so I think issue is not with ignoring css files as I did atm. Need to investigate further, what's going wrong

Comment: Also please clarify how did you find out 3.4 MB size, I don't see that info in GH

Comment: @vikramvi Click the only link in my answer, you can see a "3.4MB" above the place where the code should normally placed.

Comment: @vikramvi That repo's `src/styles/app.css` has just only 14.4KB.

Comment: Yes and I need to find out why and how ?

Comment: @vikramvi That should be another question related to the "framework", tailwind.

Comment: @vikramvi Why: Tailwind contains many CSS classes, which maybe unused at most situations (just like the rule that we use 20% functions at 80% time).

Comment: @vikramvi How: [Remove it!](https://github.com/karlhadwen/instagram/commit/aaf61834) At this commit you can see a crazy diff.

Comment: For now I've just updated app.css and removed .gitattributes file, but didn't yet figure out mystery behind massive app.css file size, once I fully understand will edit question as well for benefit of others

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to purge the unused css classes. You can refer to the official tailwind documentation on how to do that.

Comment: I think that would be only helpful in production build code.